# Rails Carrierwave & s3: wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, carrierwave, fog

new to CarrierWave, already loving it, so much better than Paperclip. Rails 3.2.1

I got it successfully working with local storage, but now trying to move to S3 and get a strange error on _url method (or the database column)

ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)

Here's my uploader:

```
class PictureUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::RMagick
  storage :fog
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end
  process :resize_to_limit => [200, 200]
  def extension_white_list
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end
end
```

Everything works fine with local storage, and with S3 / fog the file gets uploaded and resized to S3, I can see it in the bucket; there just seems to be a problem with the field / field_url method which gives the error (2 for 1)

I've set non-public s3:

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_credentials = {
  :provider               => 'AWS',       # required
  :aws_access_key_id      => 'xxx',       # required
  :aws_secret_access_key  => 'yyy',       # required
  :region                 => 'eu-west-1'  # optional, defaults to 'us-east-1'
 }
 config.fog_directory  = 'attachprod'                     # required
 config.fog_public     = false                                   # optional, defaults to true
end
```

This is in my view:

```
 <%= image_tag current_user.profile.picture_url %>
```

Full trace:

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)  
from /Users/boudewijnvandongen/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/fog-0.9.0/lib/fog/storage/models/aws/file.rb:126:in `url'
from /Users/boudewijnvandongen/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/carrierwave-0.6.0/lib/carrierwave/storage/fog.rb:148:in `authenticated_url'
from /Users/boudewijnvandongen/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/carrierwave-0.6.0/lib/carrierwave/storage/fog.rb:307:in `url'
from /Users/boudewijnvandongen/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/carrierwave-0.6.0/lib/carrierwave/uploader/url.rb:19:in `url'
from /Users/boudewijnvandongen/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/carrierwave-0.6.0/lib/carrierwave/uploader/versions.rb:159:in `url'
from /Users/boudewijnvandongen/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/carrierwave-0.6.0/lib/carrierwave/uploader/default_url.rb:8:in `url'
from /Users/boudewijnvandongen/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/carrierwave-0.6.0/lib/carrierwave/uploader/url.rb:27:in `to_s'
from /Users/boudewijnvandongen/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
from /Users/boudewijnvandongen/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
from /Users/boudewijnvandongen/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Any ideas, can't find much about this anywhere??

thnx

Comment: NB, just tested with 'config.fog_public = true' and that works fine, so must be something with the security; not sure I understand the optional 'config.fog_host' parameter, but doesn't seem to need it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out it needs an update of Fog gem to 1.3.1   All ok now

Comment: how did you figure this out? Also, did it give you a specific line in the code that was causing the error?  I am experiencing the same problem for ` <%=image_tag(prod.prod_images.first.image_url(:thumb_pic))%>`.  Thanks

Comment: hi, think I logged an issue on the carrierwave github site: https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave/issues/679?source=cc

Comment: Thanks!  Fixed my problem as well. Spent a day trying to figure out what the issue was.